# Cadence - Cadence Canary failing to start

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I am running into this error after Cadence Canary gets started on my cluster nodes.

After the error `error starting cron workflow....` , Cadence Canary does nothing and just hangs there.

[image]

Any thoughts/suggestions?

UPDATE: I have turned on debug level logging and I am getting hammered with the following (note: it's a fresh cluster):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error message says that `cadence-canary` was not able to call `cadence-frontend` service. This might indicate that `cadence-frontend` is not running or is not reachable. Check if `cadence-frontend` is running and check if your `cadence-canary` config points to correct `cadence-frontend` address

Comment: I have verified that the `cadence-canary` service is actually being started after the `cadence` service is started. Also, both services are on the same node. So I don't believe it's a reachability issue.

Comment: Can you change logging level to `debug` for `cadence-frontend` and verify that call is being made from `cadence-canary` side?

Comment: I turned on debug level logging. Nothing coming from `cadence-canary`. Also nothing showing on `cadence-canary` logs either. As soon as I restart `cadence-canary` service, things start to work. FYI, I have `cadence-canary` and `cadence` running as 2 separate docker containers on the same node.

Comment: You should use docker compose to compose the two docker containers, otherwise they won’t be able to reach each other by default unless you specify some networking rules